# AWS Athena CLI for checking the query submitter?

Tags: amazon-athena

We have multiple users that submit queries to AWS Athena concurrently.  Is there anyway  Athena CLI that allows us to find out the submitter, given a query execution id?

Based on the AWS Athena doc, it seems that this is not supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloudtrail to check the query submitter.

1. Copy with the query execution ID from the relevant query in Athena's "Recent queries" tab
2. Go to Cloudtrail
3. Search for the relevant event name (example: StartQueryExecution)
4. In the event record JSON, search for queryExecutionId inside responseElements.
5. Check the event user name, or the userIdentity arn

You may have to repeat step 4 with different events to find the event that matches your execution ID.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/monitor-with-cloudtrail.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Cloudtrail service instead.

From User guide:

> Using CloudTrail, you can determine the request that was made to Athena, the
> IP address from which the request was made, who made the request, when
> it was made, and additional details.

More details here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/monitor-with-cloudtrail.html